# How can I record video from 2 webcams?

Tags: webcam

I own 2 Logitech C-615 webcams and I want to record their footage simultaneously.
When I open Cheese I can only use one webcam, and I can't open another Cheese Window.
When I try and use both Cheese and guvcview, guvcview doesn't show a picture.

How can I get them both to work at the same time?

Thanks :-D

Answer (score 0):

What about running this in terminal:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -r 26 -i /dev/video0 -i /dev/video1 out0.avi out1.avi
```

Comment: After installing the program with the command the terminal gave me and typing the command you gave me I got this message:   ffmpeg version 0.8.9-4:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  9 2013 19:08:00 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
/dev/video0: Operation not permitted

Comment: I see. So try using `avconv` instead. Should be able to feed it the streams from the cameras.